# Including zeroes in fgetc

Tags: c, fgetc

Let's say that I have a file with contents:

0a00 910c 4e65 7467

and I want to print out every two numbers separately. My current method is to use `printf("%x\n", fgetc(file))`. But I get these as results:

- 0
- 91
- c
- 4e
- 65
- 74
- 67

My question is: where did the other zeroes go? How can I make sure that they are included too?

Comment: I know I can read as char*, but I want to know why zeroes aren't printed out when using fgetc.

Comment: Try `printf("%02x\n", fgetc(file))`

Comment: That worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The file contents are in hexadecimal. They are not "numbers" as in each one is a character. You are not printing "two numbers". You are printing one byte. The `%x` specifier is for hexadecimal.

When you do an `fgetc()`, you're getting one byte.

One byte is represented by two hexadecimal numbers. This is because one byte can have `256` values while one hexadecimal number is `16` values, and two hexadecimal numbers have a total of `256` combinations.

The characters are then listed one by one. `0a` becomes `a`. `00` becomes `0`. and so on.